# Find only common key-value pairs of several dicts: dict intersection

Tags: python

I have 0 or more `dict`s in a list:

```
>>> dicts = [dict(a=3, b=89, d=2), dict(a=3, b=89, c=99), dict(a=3, b=42, c=33)]
```

I want to create a new dict that contains only keys that are in **all** the above dicts, and only if the values are all the same:

```
>>> dict_intersection(*dicts)
{"a": 3}
```

I feel that there should be an *elegant* way of writing `dict_intersection`, but I'm only coming up with inelegant and/or inefficient solutions myself.

Comment: You forgot the string literal quotes in your example. ;) Interesting question - I will meditate on this and return.

Comment: And of course, what have you come yup with so far?

Comment: @Li-aung: String literal quotes are not needed when instanciating `dict` like a class. I find it a very handy shortcut to avoid those pesky quotes.

Comment: @lazyr: Well hey, you learn something every day!

Comment: Interesting would be a similar question: at least in one dictionary and no differences.

Comment: @hochl: How about this? `{k:count for k,count in collections.Counter(itertools.chain(*[d.iteritems() for d in dicts])) if count > 1}`

Comment: The output should be `{'a': 3, 'd': 2}`, i.e. all keys that are in at least one dictionary and if they are in more than one they may not be different [I have a maybe clumsy solution for this one because I misread the question ^^].

Comment: Whoops, I missed that iterating over a `Counter` only iterates only the keys (not the counts.) Here's one that works: `{k:count for k,count in collections.Counter(itertools.chain(*[d.iteritems() for d in dicts])).iteritems() if count > 1}` . Though this isn't really "elegant" anymore - it's a fairly deeply nested one-liner that's not at all easy to understand.

Comment: Wow that's what I call a one-liner :^) It's returning `{('a', 3): 3, ('b', 89): 2}` tho ... :( Maybe I should open a separate question for this one.

Comment: @hochl: Do feel free to open a separate question. I'm curious to see if anyone can improve on the one-liner I've provided. (And my version returns counts intentionally; it's a trivial change to return the original dict entries instead.)

Comment: Ok, I've started a new thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9908777/589206).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
>>> dict(set.intersection(*(set(d.iteritems()) for d in dicts)))
{'a': 3}
```

Note: This solution requires the dictionary values to be hashable, in addition to the keys.

Comment: Well, you have me beat. Once again proving that a set intersection operation is best performed using `set` operations. ;)

Comment: Lets hope they add set operators to dict. They recently added union `|`, but intersection `&` is yet to be added. With that the answer would simply be `d1 & d2` and one could use itertools.reduce for multiple dicts.

Answer (score 5):

Since the key/value pairs must already be in the first dict, you can iterate over this dict's items.

```
dict(pair for pair in dicts[0].items() 
     if all((pair in d.items() for d in dicts[1:])))
```

Looks less elegant than interjay's answer, but works without the restriction of hashable values.

Edit: Changed the `all` expression to a generator expression for speed improvement

Comment: +1 I think this is pretty elegant because it works for non-hashables.

Comment: @jamylak how can use it in case of list of dict where values are non hashable. the above one works only to find common items in first dict and other dict in the list.

Answer (score 4):

How's this?

```
def intersect_two_dicts (d1, d2):
    return { k:v for k,v in d1.iteritems() if ((k in d2)and(d1[k]==d2[k])) }

def intersect_dicts (list_of_dicts):
    return reduce(intersect_two_dicts, list_of_dicts)

# Tests
dicts = [dict(a=3, b=89, d=2), dict(a=3, b=89, c=99), dict(a=3, b=42, c=33)]
print (intersect_two_dicts(dicts[0], dicts[1]))
print (intersect_dicts(dicts))
```

Edit(1): I'm not sure which of these is fastest. The `set.intersection` solutions are certainly most elegant (*short* one liners!) but I would be interested to see some benchmarking.

Edit(2): Bonus - get any dictionary entries whose (key:value) pairs are common to any two dictionaries:

```
{k:count for k,count in
 collections.Counter(itertools.chain(*[d.iteritems() for d in dicts])).iteritems()
 if count > 1}
```

Comment: It says name reduce is not defined

Comment: @learnningprogramming if you are using Python 3, `reduce()` is now `import functools`, `functools.reduce()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> dicts
[{'a': 3, 'b': 89, 'd': 2}, {'a': 3, 'c': 99, 'b': 89}, {'a': 3, 'c': 33, 'b': 42}]
>>> sets = (set(d.iteritems()) for d in dicts)
>>> dict_intersection = dict(set.intersection(*sets))
>>> dict_intersection
{'a': 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more hands-dirty approach: Take the list of keys for each dictionary, sort each list, and then proceed as if you were merging them (keep an index for each list, advance the one w/ the lowest value).  Whenever all of the indices point to the same key, check the values for equality; either way, advance all indices.

Comment: Conceptually elegant, but sorting seems like it would be expensive. It also seems like you would need a lot of "plumbing" code (though judicious use of `itertools` might help.)