# Create a dictionary of non-contradicting items from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

This question is inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9906944/589206). I'd like to get a dictionary from a list of dictionaries that should contain all key/value pairs from all dictionaries that are either only contained once, or where all dictionaries agree on the associated value. Example (taken from the aforementioned posting):

```
dicts = [dict(a=3, b=89, d=2), dict(a=3, b=89, c=99), dict(a=3, b=42, c=33)]
print dict_itersection(dicts)
```

should yield

```
{'a': 3, 'd': 2}
```

My current implementation looks like this:

```
import collections

def dict_intersection(dicts):
        c=collections.defaultdict(set)
        for d in dicts:
                for a, b in d.iteritems():
                        c[a].add(b)
        return {a: next(iter(b)) for a, b in c.iteritems() if len(b) == 1}
```

So my question: *Can this be done more elegantly?*

*Sidequestion: can `next(iter(b))` be done better without modification of the underlying dictionary (i.e. not `b.pop()`)?*

Comment: All it needs are two comments. `b.pop()` would be fine here as it only modifies your new, temporary sets. There is no other way to get a single item from a set. because sets have no order and thus no `myset[0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All solutions so far assume that all dictionary values are hashable.  Since the code won't get slower and only little more complex without this assumption, I'd drop it.  Here's a version that works for all values that support `!=`:

```py
def dict_intersection(dicts):
    result = {}
    conflicting = set()
    for d in dicts:
        for k, v in d.iteritems():
            if k not in conflicting and result.setdefault(k, v) != v:
                del result[k]
                conflicting.add(k)
    return result
```

The set `conflicting` will only contain dictionary keys, which will always be hashable.

Comment: This is really simple and works for cases where all other solutions don't, so I'll accept this one.

Answer (score 4):

Yours is pretty close to as elegant as I can think of. The only change I would make is to replaced the nested for loop with a `itertools.chain()`'ed iterator, like this:

```
import collections

def dict_intersection(dicts):
        c=collections.defaultdict(set)
        for k,v in itertools.chain(*[d.iteritems() for d in dicts]):
                c[k].add(v)
        return {a: next(iter(b)) for a, b in c.iteritems() if len(b) == 1}
```

---

Edit(1): The below code answers a slightly different question - how to get any entry which appears with the same key and value in at least two of the input dictionaries.

My answer from the comments in the other question:

```
dict(
    [k for k,count in
     collections.Counter(itertools.chain(*[d.iteritems() for d in dicts])).iteritems()
     if count > 1]
    )
```

This is nominally a "one-liner" but I've spread it over multiple lines to (hopefully) make it a bit clearer.

The way it works is (starting from the inside and working out):

- Use `itertools.chain()` to get an iterator over the elements of all the dictionaries.
- Use `collections.Counter()` to count how many times each `key, value` pair appears in the dictionaries.
- Use a list comprehension to filter the `Counter` for those `key, value` pairs occurring at least twice.
- Convert the list back into a dict.

Answer (score 4):

```
dicts = [dict(a=3, b=89, d=2), dict(a=3, b=89, c=99), dict(a=3, b=42, c=33)]

data = {}
for d in dicts:
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        data.setdefault(k, set()).add(v)
out = dict((k, v.pop()) for k, v in data.iteritems() if len(v) == 1)

# out == {'a': 3, 'd': 2}
```

… or a one-liner:

```
import itertools as it

dict((k, v.pop()[1]) for k,v in ((k, set(v)) for k, v in it.groupby(sorted(it.chain(*(d.iteritems() for d in dicts))), key=lambda x: x[0])) if len(v) == 1)
```

Comment: Neato! Could also use `key = operator.itemgetter(0)`. Note this is neater in Py3k, since you can use dict and set liberals and you don't need to call `.iteritems()`.

Answer (score 1):

To get the intersection:

```
dict(reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, map(set, map(lambda x: x.iteritems(), dicts))))
```

Of course, this drops unique values, so we need to get the complement:

```
dict(reduce(lambda x, y: x - y, map(set, map(lambda x: x.iteritems(), dicts))))
```

Combining the resulting dictionaries gives us the result set:

```
def dict_intersection(d):
    x = dict(reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, map(set, map(lambda x: x.iteritems(), dicts))))
    y = dict(reduce(lambda x, y: x - y, map(set, map(lambda x: x.iteritems(), dicts))))
    return dict(x.items() + y.items())
```

If my set fu was stronger I could get it down to a one liner, but not today it seems.

Comment: Unfortunately this will fail for `[{'a': 3, 'b': 89, 'd': 2}, {'a': 3, 'c': 99, 'b': 89}, {'a': 3, 'c': 33, 'b': 42}, {'x': 5}]` (although I like the idea of set operations much). Additionally I think you can compress your statements into `tmp=[set(d.iteritems()) for d in dicts]; return dict(set.intersection(*tmp).union(set.difference(*tmp)))`