# Intersection of two lists of dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

Simular to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906944/python-find-only-common-key-value-pairs-of-several-dicts-dict-intersection) question, I want to know the intersection between two lists of dictionaries.

The other questions asks how to get the intersection of the dictionaries inside the list:

```
>>> dicts = [dict(a=3, b=89, d=2), dict(a=3, b=89, c=99), dict(a=3, b=42, c=33)]
```

and the solution was:

```
dict(set.intersection(*(set(d.iteritems()) for d in dicts)))
```

However I would like to know how to get the intersection of two list of dictionaries and **not** get the intersection of the inside dictionaries.

if I had:

```
>>> dicts1 = [dict(a=3, b=89, d=2), dict(a=3, b=89, c=99), dict(a=3, b=42, c=33)]
>>> dicts2 = [dict(a=3, b=89, d=2), dict(a=1, b=89, c=99), dict(a=0, b=42, c=33)]
```

I want

```
{a=3m, b=89, b=42}
```

to print not because it happens in all of the dictionaries in dicts1 but because it happens in a dictionary in dicts1 and a dictionary in dict2.  I dont care where in each array. Just that it happens.

Comment: what about `b=89`? Would it qualify?

Comment: I agree with @1_CR... there are many things that pass your criteria in the given example... why should it only return `{a=3}`?

Comment: The way the question is currently phrased, you're asking for a list that contains the dicts contained in both input lists. I don't think that's what you want to ask.

Comment: What should happen if `dicts1` and `dicts2` are both `[{'a': 0}, {'a': 1}]`?

Comment: You guys are right. I have edited the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this (note that if you have a fixed list of keys, you don't need the first line):

```
keys = set([y for x in dicts1 for y in x.keys() ] + [y for x in dicts2 for y in x.keys() ])

for key in keys:
    valsDicts1 = set([x[key] for x in dicts1 if key in x])
    valsDicts2 = set([x[key] for x in dicts2 if key in x])
    print key, list(valsDicts1 & valsDicts2)
```

Prints with your example:

```
a [3]
c [33, 99]
b [89, 42]
d [2]
```

Obviously if you don't want to print it, do something else with the last line.