# read many json files to find common key value pair python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

i have a list of paths to json files.

```
files = ['/Users/sbm/Downloads/ds214mb/sub-EESS001/sub-EESS001_task-Cyberball_bold.json',
 '/Users/sbm/Downloads/ds214mb/sub-EESS002/func/sub-EESS002_task-Cyberball_bold.json',
 '/Users/sbm/Downloads/ds214mb/sub-EESS003/sub-EESS003_task-Cyberball_bold.json',
 '/Users/sbm/Downloads/ds214mb/sub-EESS004/func/sub-EESS004_task-Cyberball_bold.json',
 '/Users/sbm/Downloads/ds214mb/sub-EESS005/sub-EESS005_task-Cyberball_bold.json',
 '/Users/sbm/Downloads/ds214mb/sub-EESS006/sub-EESS006_task-Cyberball_bold.json',
 '/Users/sbm/Downloads/ds214mb/sub-EESS007/func/sub-EESS007_task-Cyberball_bold.json',
 '/Users/sbm/Downloads/ds214mb/sub-EESS008/func/sub-EESS008_task-Cyberball_bold.json']
```

Now i intend to read all these files into dictionaries with same name as filename or diff name. And then iterate through those dict to find common key value pair.

I did the following to read all json files to diff dict. Now what would be an efficient way to compare all these dict to find common key: value pair?

```
import json
for file in range(0, len(files)):
    globals()['json%s' % file] = "Hello"

i = 0
for file in files:
    globals()['json%s' % i] = json.loads(open(file).read())
    i = i+1
```

sample json file looks like:

```
{
 'Manufacturer': 'Siemens',
 'ManufacturerModelName': 'Magnetom Verio',
 'RepetitionTime': 1.56,
 'SliceTiming': [0.0,
  0.78,
  0.06,
  0.84,
  0.12],
 'TaskName': 'Cyberball'}
```

Comment: if you could organize the dicts into a list, check this other answer out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906944/python-find-only-common-key-value-pairs-of-several-dicts-dict-intersection

Comment: Look here maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25851183/how-to-compare-two-json-objects-with-the-same-elements-in-a-different-order-equa

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question....

I start with piping a list of JSON Files ....

```
find <dir> | grep json$
```

That pipe gets sent to a python program....

So this now looks like

```
find <dir> | grep json$ | python t.py
```

The python code does the following

1. Opens the file
2. Reads the file
3. JSON Parses into Python Dictionary
4. Outputs the python Dictionary

So this looks like this (Python3 code)

```
import json,sys,pprint
for file in sys.stdin:
  file=file.strip('\n')
  with open(file,"rt") as ifp:
    b=ifp.read()
    b=(b.replace('\n','')).replace("'","\"")
  ifp.close()
  c=json.loads(b)
  for k,v in c.items():
    print('{}:{}'.format(k,v))
```

We now sort and count the output using bash... which generically looks like this...

```
sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

So putting all this together we get ... (I am assuming all the JSON in same directory as I am at the moment)

```
ls *.json | python t.py | sort  | uniq -c  | sort -n
```

If you want the top 5 - it becomes

```
ls *.json | python t.py | sort  | uniq -c  | sort -n | head -n 5
```

Comment: here the issue is i intend to do this in python

Comment: Ok ... I will post a full Python way

Answer (score 1):

Only in python - no linux

```
files=['data1.json','data2.json','data3.json']
master_key_plus_value={}
import json,sys,pprint
for file in files:
  with open(file,"rt") as ifp:
    b=ifp.read()
    b=(b.replace('\n','')).replace("'","\"")
  ifp.close()
  c=json.loads(b)
  for k,v in c.items():
    if str(k)+': '+str(v) in master_key_plus_value:
        master_key_plus_value[str(k)+': '+str(v)] += 1
    else:
        master_key_plus_value[str(k)+': '+str(v)] = 1

#Now we have ready all the key + values into a single dictionary
#Sort by the value (occurance)



master_key

sorted_dictionary = sorted(master_key_plus_value.items(), key=lambda x: -x[1])

print("Most Common Key-Value is  {} Occurance {} ".format(sorted_dictionary[0][0],sorted_dictionary[0][1]))
```

Same principles 
  for each file
   read JSON file as text
   reformat and make Json object which gives a python dictionary
   combine key + value and compare to a master dictionary
     add 1 to value if there
   else
     store and set value to 1
Finally Sort on value descending
print top element ([0]) which is a tuple hence it is [0][0] and [0][1]